# Dropwizard hibernate field not populating

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, h2, dropwizard

I've got a very simple User Entity which populates a username and password field from a (h2) database.

I seem unable to add a further field though for a `boolean isAdmin` - I've tried primitive and object Boolean. The SQL hibernate executes is logged and when I run it returns all the fields from the user table for the given user including the `boolean` value (`true`). Yet the `Boolean` remains `null`.

Any ideas how I can get this field populating?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(
        name = "eu.wansdyke.smaash.core.User.findAll",
        query = "SELECT u FROM User u"
    ),
    @NamedQuery(
        name = "eu.wansdyke.smaash.core.User.deleteByUsername",
        query = "DELETE FROM User WHERE username = :username"
    ),
    @NamedQuery(
        name = "eu.wansdyke.smaash.core.User.findByUsername",
        query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.username = :username"
    )
})
@NamedNativeQueries({
    @NamedNativeQuery(
        name = "eu.wansdyke.smaash.core.User.setPassword",
        query = "merge into users (username, password) key(username) values (:username, :password)"
    )
})
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "username", nullable = false)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "isadmin", nullable = false)
    private Boolean isAdmin;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public Boolean isAdmin() {
        return isAdmin;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the way which is pure OOP is to use a full constructor (without id)

```
public User(String username, String password, Boolean isAdmin) {
  this.username = username;
  this.password = password;
  this.isAdmin = isAdmin;
}
```

Now, you can initialize the field before you save it to the database.

Comment: The field value is in the database, it's on reading it back that it's not populated.

Comment: It should be populated, by this constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

The dropwizard authenticator code I was using was creating a User object itself, not using a hibernate retrieved object. The hibernate code is fine.